# ошибка при отслеживании объекта opencv

Tags: opencv

код для обнаружения зрачка в реальном времени

````
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret is False:
        break

    roi = frame[269: 795, 537: 1416]
    rows, cols, _ = roi.shape
    gray_roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_roi = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_roi, (7, 7), 0)

    _, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_roi, 3, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)

    for cnt in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

        #cv2.drawContours(roi, [cnt], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.rectangle(roi, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        cv2.line(roi, (x + int(w/2), 0), (x + int(w/2), rows), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.line(roi, (0, y + int(h/2)), (cols, y + int(h/2)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        break

    cv2.imshow("Threshold", threshold)
    cv2.imshow("gray roi", gray_roi)
    cv2.imshow("Roi", roi)
    key = cv2.waitKey(30)
    if key == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()```

выдает ошибку 
line 17, in <module>
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
почему, и как это исправить?
````

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Начиная с версии 3.2 findContours выдает  двухэлементный кортеж, а не трехэлементный.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```